# Angularfire data not updating when changing routes

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I"m using Angularfire 0.8.2.  When I change routes on my app, the url changes to the correct route, but the data on the screen doesn't change unless I refresh.  I've tried doing $route.reload().  I was able to hack around to get it to work on older versions of angularfire using $on().  In my service is have

```
'use strict';

app.factory('GetSt', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $routeParams) {

var gstRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'newdrips/'+$routeParams.ncampid);

var gStarts = $firebase(gstRef).$asObject();

var GetSt = {
    mydrip: gStarts

}
 return GetSt;
```

In controller I have tried

```
use strict';
 app.controller('GStartCtrl', function($scope, User,  GetSt, Auth, $routeParams) {

GetSt.mydrip.$loaded(function () {
    $scope.dripinfo = GetSt.mydrip

})
 //and i've tried
$scope.dripinfo = GetSt.mydrip; });
```

routeprovider

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

    .when('/getstarted/:ncampid', {
        templateUrl: 'views/getstarted.html',
        controller: 'GStartCtrl'
    })
```

Comment: Are you setting up your `$routeProvider` anywhere? If so, that code seems relevant to (and missing from) the question. Snippet from one of my apps: `app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'boards.html', controller: 'BoardListCtrl' }).when('/board/:boardId', { templateUrl: 'board.html', controller: 'BoardCtrl' })`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.  I've updated the question with my $routeProvider data

Comment: All looks kosher so far. It's pretty hard to help you troubleshoot without a minimal reproduction of the problem. Can you set one up on jsfiddle/jsbin? Aside from that: have a look at https://trenches.firebaseapp.com/ as an example of a tiny app that uses routes.

Comment: hi, i moved the code from my service into my controller and it works fine, so I'm guessing I have to resolve the service before the route is loaded in routeProvider.  I will put up a jsfiddle.  thanks again

Comment: A service is like a singleton in other frameworks, there is only one of the service and it's (to my knowledge) created/initialized only once. So that indeed explains why you only got the initial route working. I missed that detail in the information you provided. No need for a fiddle if it now works.

Comment: Perhaps updating the question to include the service code and to reflect the true nature of the problem (how to create a service that is specific to each controller's scope) would help others in the future (and is a question we can easily answer here)

Comment: Hey Kato, I've updated the question to show all of the code in the GetSt service.